# I added some animations on the button by style triggers, but the second animation on the same property doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

Here is my XAML code.

```xml
<Window x:Class="TestWpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="320" Width="340">
    <Window.Resources>
        <QuadraticEase x:Key="easing" EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Label Name="label"/>
            <Button Content="Hello" Width="100" Height="45">
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Button">
                        <Style.Resources>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="press" x:Name="press">
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="125" Duration="0:0:0.100" EasingFunction="{StaticResource easing}"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="50" Duration="0:0:0.100" EasingFunction="{StaticResource easing}"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="hover" x:Name="hover">
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="120" Duration="0:0:0.200" EasingFunction="{StaticResource easing}"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="45" Duration="0:0:0.200" EasingFunction="{StaticResource easing}"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="leave" x:Name="leave">
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="100" Duration="0:0:0.300" EasingFunction="{StaticResource easing}"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="45" Duration="0:0:0.300" EasingFunction="{StaticResource easing}"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </Style.Resources>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource press}"/>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource hover}"/>
                                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource hover}"/>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource leave}"/>
                                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

You can see that I specified a style for the button, and added some triggers that can do some animation when I move the mouse or click the mouse button.

When I move my mouse to the button, the button size turns 120x45. But when I pressed the mouse button after that, nothing happened.

What I want:

1. Button default size is 100x45
2. When the mouse is hovering, the button size will change to 120x45 (width increased by 20) through animation, and when not hovering, the size will be restored
3. When the mouse is pressed, the size will change to 125x50 through animation (the width and height increase by 5), and when the mouse is released, the size will restore

Comment: Name animations (`BeginStoryboard`) and stop conflicting animations with StopStoryboard before starting a new animation.

Comment: The above code has added Name to the three Storyboards, even if I add StopStoryboard before BeginStoryboard, it will throw an exception that the Storyboard cannot be found

Answer (score 2):

> even if I add StopStoryboard before BeginStoryboard, it will throw an exception that the Storyboard cannot be found.

I ran your XAML with these changes and everything works fine for me:

```xml
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Label x:Name="label" Content="LABEL"/>
    <Button Content="Hello" Width="100" Height="45">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="press" x:Name="press">
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="200" Duration="0:0:0.100" EasingFunction="{StaticResource easing}"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="100" Duration="0:0:0.100" EasingFunction="{StaticResource easing}"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="hover" x:Name="hover">
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="120" Duration="0:0:0.200" EasingFunction="{StaticResource easing}"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="45" Duration="0:0:0.200" EasingFunction="{StaticResource easing}"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="leave" x:Name="leave">
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="100" Duration="0:0:0.300" EasingFunction="{StaticResource easing}"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="45" Duration="0:0:0.300" EasingFunction="{StaticResource easing}"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </Style.Resources>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="IsMouseOverTrue"/>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource press}"/>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource hover}"/>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="IsMouseOverTrue" Storyboard="{StaticResource hover}"/>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource leave}"/>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, it turned out to add Name for StartStoryboard, I thought it was for Storyboard. Thank you very much!